# Make it simpler, pandas multiple filer iteration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
files=glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in files:

    df=pd.read_csv(file, header= None)
    output_file_name = "output_" + file
    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write("sum of the 1. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 0].sum())+"\n")
        f.write("sum of the 2. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 1].sum())+"\n")
        f.write("sum of the 3. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 2].sum())+"\n")
        f.write("sum of the 4. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 3].sum())+"\n")

        f.write("max of the 1. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 0].max()) + "\n")
        f.write("max of the 2. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 1].max()) + "\n")
        f.write("max of the 3. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 2].max()) + "\n")
        f.write("max of the 4. column is " + str(df.iloc[:, 3].max()) + "\n")

    f.close()
```

How can iterate trough my pandas files, so that i dont have to repeat all this lines again. I want the same output file with this information about max and sum.
For every csv file i want a new file in the same folder that describe the max, sum , stdn etc. for example the output file will be:

```
sum of the 1. column is 21
sum of the 2. column is 23
sum of the 3. column is 33
sum of the 4. column is 30
max of the 1. column is 6
max of the 2. column is 6
max of the 3. column is 8
max of the 4. column is 9
```

How can it make simpler :D :D
Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select first 4 columns, then apply function by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), create columns starting with `1`, reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), create list with list comprehension and last write to file by [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html):

```
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header= None)
    df1 = df.iloc[:, :4].agg(['sum','max','std'])
    df1.columns = range(1, len(df1.columns) + 1)
    s = df1.stack()
    L = ['{} of the {}. column is {}'.format(a, b, c) for (a, b), c in s.items()]

    output_file_name = "output_" + file
    pd.Series(L).to_csv(output_file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Tnx very much, it was very helpfull, how can i add to this output file the info of size of input and output file...ex: The size of input file is ..., i asssume that i will use os.path.getsize but how can it write it in this output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a double for-loop to iterate over all the functions and columns:

```
for funcname in ['sum', 'max', 'std']:
    for i in range(len(df.columns)):
        f.write("sum of the {} column is {}\n"
                .format(i+1, getattr(df.iloc[:, 0], funcname)()))
```

[`getattr(df, 'sum')` is equivalent to `df.sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

---

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
for file in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    output_file_name = "output_" + file
    with open(output_file_name, 'w') as f:
        # f.write("{}\n".format(df.describe()))
        for funcname in ['sum', 'max', 'std']:
            for i in range(len(df.columns)):
                f.write("sum of the {} column is {}\n"
                        .format(i+1, getattr(df.iloc[:, 0], funcname)()))
```

---

Note that `df.describe()` presents summary statistics in a neat format. You might want to consider just printing `df.describe()`:

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,6)))

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.791727  0.397873  0.924195  0.202464  0.789961  0.077095
1  0.920516  0.637618  0.383694  0.623393  0.328440  0.606576
2  0.844562  0.231242  0.183842  0.902065  0.286643  0.743508
3  0.411101  0.370284  0.249545  0.955745  0.561450  0.597586
4  0.185035  0.989508  0.522821  0.218888  0.569865  0.773848
5  0.196904  0.377201  0.816561  0.914657  0.482806  0.686805
6  0.809536  0.480733  0.397394  0.152101  0.645284  0.921204
7  0.004433  0.168943  0.865408  0.472513  0.188554  0.012219
8  0.534432  0.739246  0.628112  0.789579  0.268880  0.835339
9  0.701573  0.580974  0.858254  0.461687  0.493617  0.285601

In [28]: df.describe()
Out[28]: 
               0          1          2          3          4          5
count  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000  10.000000
mean    0.539982   0.497362   0.582983   0.569309   0.461550   0.553978
std     0.324357   0.246491   0.274233   0.313254   0.189960   0.318598
min     0.004433   0.168943   0.183842   0.152101   0.188554   0.012219
25%     0.250453   0.372014   0.387119   0.279588   0.297092   0.363598
50%     0.618003   0.439303   0.575466   0.547953   0.488212   0.646691
75%     0.805084   0.623457   0.847830   0.873943   0.567761   0.766263
max     0.920516   0.989508   0.924195   0.955745   0.789961   0.921204
```